# Report Builder Treat my DataSet like a Table

Tags: dataset, reportbuilder3.0

I'm swimming in ignorance here.  New to Report Builder.  (Using Ver. 3.0)

I have a DataSet named DemographicData.  It has the following fields: EID, Department, Years, Months, Days, Gender, and BenCat.

For the purposes of this question, let's say I want to get CountRows(EID) where Gender = 'M' and similarly where it = 'F'

I've tried for two days now, and cannot get this to work.  How do I treat my DataSet like a Table so I can query against it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a text box for you to display the daya on.
2. Right click in the text box and add an expression.
3. Enter the following type of expression:

   ```
   =Sum(IIf(Fields!Gender="M", 1, 0), "MyDataset")
   ```

Similarly for `Gender ="F"`

Sorry if the synax is a little out, I don't have the app with me.